Can't Debug When Calling Function From Cell
I'm trying to call a function from a formula in a cell. In this case:
=CompareColors(test1, test2)
Where test1 and test2 are named ranges. The function returns the value as expected, but I'm never able to step through the code, even though I put a breakpoint on the debug statement.
Here's my function:
Public Function CompareColors(answerRange As Range, compareRange As Range) As Long

  Dim rng1 As Range: rng1 = answerRange
  Dim rng2 As Range: rng2 = compareRange
  Dim answer as Long

  answer = 2

  debug.print "heh" 'breakpoint is here
  
  CompareColors = answer


End Function


I want to build my function further, but can't figure out why I'm not able to step through it. Thanks!

I tried using Stop, but it seems to be ignored. Still returns 2 even when stop is before answer=2

Breakpoints perfectly work in functions.

The problem is in the code error:
  Dim rng1 As Range: Set rng1 = answerRange
  Dim rng2 As Range: Set rng2 = compareRange

You missed the Set keyword which is required for object assigning.
You should notice your code returns the #VALUE! error which tells that something wrong inside the function body.
To debug a function better, just call it from any subroutine.
Sub TestMyFunction
  CompareColors [A1], [B1]
End Sub


lol, Thanks. And thanks for the tip!
